# Wallet Selection Modal

Tags: wallet, polkadot-js-extension, metamask

I am working with the team that is developing [the MetaMask snap for Polkadot-like networks](https://github.com/ChainSafe/metamask-snap-polkadot). In addition to this wallet and [the well known Polkadot-JS extension](https://github.com/polkadot-js/extension), there are [Nova Wallet](https://novawallet.io/), [Talisman](https://talisman.xyz/), and I'm sure many others. The Ethereum ecosystem maintains [a modal to make it easy for dApp developers to support multiple wallets](https://github.com/Web3Modal/web3modal), as does [the Near ecosystem](https://github.com/near/wallet-selector). Is there an established/preferred pattern for dealing with the multiple wallets that exist in the Polkadot ecosystem? If such a solution doesn't currently exist, would a solution similar to the Ethereum/Near solutions be a desirable addition to the Polkadot ecosystem?

Comment: Just wondering if you could update us on this solution? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

A similar solution to support multi-wallet on polkadot ecosystem is in progress right now. I'll keep you posted once we are close to release.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).